# Changing the method call dynamically, without using case statements

Tags: java

How can I modify the following code to make it execute method represented by "some_variable", instead of just "get(uri)", without using case statements?

```java
SimpleHttpRequest http_request = SimpleRequestBuilder.get(uri)
    .setBody(request_body)
    .setHeaders(request_headers)
    .build();
```

For example, assuming that `String some_variable = "post";`, I would like my program to do the following:

```java
SimpleHttpRequest http_request = SimpleRequestBuilder.post(uri)
    .setBody(request_body)
    .setHeaders(request_headers)
    .build()
```

Because I'd like to minimize my code as much as I can, I don't want to use "if" statements or "case" statements. The `SimpleRequestBuilder` call should change dynamically, no matter what value `some_variable` contains.

Comment: Too little information to help for this request

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is. The obvious answer would be an `if()` statement, but that is most likely not what you have in mind. Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have.

Comment: @Progman I added the additional explanation of what i want to achieve at the end of the question. Will that do?

Comment: @netcat_dd No, it doesn't explain why you don't want to use `if()` or `switch()`. You can use "reflection" to find the correct method, but that is overkill for what you are trying to do. Please [edit] your question to explain why exactly `if()` or `switch()` is not a reliable solution/approach in your case. It is still not clear what the problem is.

Comment: @Progman I already stated that i would like to minimize my code as much as possible. This is the reason, i do not have any additional reasons for my question. 
Why do you think "reflection" would be overkill? Also, i would like to understand how to handle similar situations in future.

Comment: The version with the minimum amount of code will use ifs and switches.

Comment: @LouisWasserman i doubt that. Please consider that HTTP has 8 + custom verbs.

Comment: You don’t need to execute different methods.  I assume you’re using Apache’s SimpleRequestBuilder, which has a [create(String)](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-5.2.x/current/httpclient5/apidocs/org/apache/hc/client5/http/async/methods/SimpleRequestBuilder.html#create-java.lang.String-) method.  You can just write `SimpleRequestBuilder.create(someVariable).setURI(uri).setBody(requestBody)` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid using `if` or `switch` statements but it won't "minimize" your code to any significant degree.

For example, the following approach makes use of function references:

```
Map<String, Function<URI, SimpleRequestBuilder>> method_mapping = 
new HashMap<>() {{
   put("get", SimpleRequestBuilder::get);
   put("post", SimpleRequestBuilder::post);
}}

SimpleHttpRequest http_request = method_mapping.get(method)
    .apply(uri)
    .setBody(request_body)
    .setHeaders(request_headers)
    .build();
```

But this is more or less equivalent to a `switch` statement or a chain of `if` statements.  And ... more complicated, IMO.

---

> The `SimpleRequestBuilder` call should change dynamically, no matter what value `some_variable` contains.

Well to the extent that it is possible, the above `Map` approach does that.  But the problem is that if `method_mapping` doesn't have an entry for a specific method string, then **no scheme** will be able to handle this.

(The code should really test that `method_mapping.get(method)` returns a non-null function reference before it tries to call it.)

---

And here's a version using a Java 12+ `switch` expression:

```
Function<URI, SimpleRequestBuilder> request_builder = 
switch(method) {
    case "get" -> SimpleRequestBuilder::get;
    case "post" -> SimpleRequestBuilder::post;
    default -> DummyBuilder::error405;
}
request_builder
    .apply(uri)
    .setBody(request_body)
    .setHeaders(request_headers)
    .build();
```

where `DummyBuilder::error405` handles the case of an unsupported method.

Comment: Can you evaluate on "method_mapping.get(method)(uri)"? this doesn't seem to work. It says "Cannot resolve method 'setBody' in 'URI'" and the program doesn't recognize the "(uri)" parameter in ".get(method)(uri)" snippet

Comment: Ah.  Maybe `Consumer<URI>` should be `Function<URI, SimpleRequestBuilder>`.  Try it and let me know.

Comment: `method_mapping.get(method)(uri)` is not valid Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection, but it won't be elegant.

You can minimise the code by first creating a request, then applying the common code:

```
SimpleHttpRequest http_request = (some_variable.equals("post") ? SimpleRequestBuilder.post(uri) : SimpleRequestBuilder.get(uri))
  .setBody(request_body)
  .setHeaders(request_headers)
  .build();
```